# Gentoo: No package `glib-2.0` found

Tags: gentoo, pkg-config, glib

I have a strange problem when trying to install `dev-lib/gobject-introspection`:

```
>>> Emerging (1 of 9) dev-libs/gobject-introspection-1.42.0 
...... 
configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 > 2.36.0) were not met: 

No package `glib-2.0` found
```

I have `dev-libs/glib-2.42.1` installed, but there is some strange issue with `pkg-config`:

```
$ pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0 
Package glib-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path. 
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `glib-2.0.pc` 
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable 
No package 'glib-2.0' found 

$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH 

$
```

And looks like there is no `glib-2.0.pc` file in `/usr/lib/pkgconfig` . There is the file `/usr/lib32/pkgconfig/glib-2.0.pc`, but for previous version of glib-2.38.2

Can anybody explain to me, what can be wrong and how can fix this? I've already asked this question on the [gentoo forum](http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1009800-highlight-.html), but maybe I'll have better luck here.

Answer (score 24):

An alternative answer, one that doesn't involve pulling in nearly as many unneeded packages, is:

`sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev`

Comment: apt doesn't exist on gentoo by default...

Comment: Got same error as OP when trying to install a python module via pip on raspberry.
Installing `libglib2.0-dev` did the trick

Comment: Worked perfectly on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: For those who stumble on this question, it's `glib2-devel` using yum.